# How to execute Javascript from button click on d365 F&O

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I need to know if it's possible to execute Javascript from a button click on d365 F&O.  If so, how to do that?

I'm needing to call a URL that is only available inside of our customer's local network - it's not available over the Internet.  So, I'm thinking Javascript is my only option.  Not sure if this is possible in d365.  Any help would be great.

TIA!

Comment: What kind of button it is? If it is custom button, add the entity in a solution. Add a js file in CRM and add a method inside the method call the url using ajax/REST call. Open the solution in ribbon workbench and add the method from that new js and publish. For more info refer this url https://www.briteglobal.com/blogs/community/create-ribbon-button-using-ribbon-workbench/

Comment: Second approach is (secured than first one), create a custom Workflow to call the url and add that custom workflow as step in action. Call that action in button click using ribbonworkbench  same as above.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Sadly, I'm trying to make this change in F&O and not CRM.